Setting @State value causes app to freeze
I have an issue where the following code causes my app to hang. All of this is wrapped in a navigation stack at the top level of my app.
struct ParentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        List {
           Section {
                ForEach(0...5, id: \.self) { i in
                    NavigationLink {
                        ChildView()
                    } label: {
                        Text("Tap here")
                    }  
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ChildView: View {
    @State var viewModel: ChildViewModel
    
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    init() {
        _viewModel = State(initialValue: ChildViewModel())
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

@Observable class ChildViewModel {
    // Empty
}

I've isolated it down to the initialiser of the ChildView class, but can't figure out exactly what is causing it to lock up. If I change the ChildView class to look like this it works just fine:
struct ChildView: View {
    // MARK: - Lifecycle
    init() { }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello, World!")
    }
}

I've tried using State(wrappedValue: viewModel) as well, with no luck. I've also tried profiling the app but it doesn't seem to actually be able to pick up the cause of the hang either.

But your view model class isn’t really empty, right?

Correct. But even empty it still freezes.

Maybe the problem is that it’s nothing making each child view unique and that creates the issue try adding an .id modifier to the view

I cannot reproduce on iOS 17.4. Please show some code that would reproduce the problem when pasted into a brand new Xcode project.

You should use @StateObject instead of @State if you don't want to re-create the ChildViewModel over and over again. Or better, create it beforehand and iterate over a array of your child view models instead of 0...5. Essentially your entire code structure is just wrong, and trying to fix wrong code is somewhat meaningless.

In SwiftUI the View struct is the view model and state is for a dynamic value source of truth. So trying to put a view model in a state is the wrong way around.

@ClausJørgensen in what what is it "entirely wrong". That seems a subjective opinion that you've provided no backing for? @StateObject is the newer way of doing this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/migrating-from-the-observable-object-protocol-to-the-observable-macro

@BrandonStillitano no, StateObject like I said, is for when you don't want to re-create the view model every time you create the view. But the correct approach is to inject the view model and create it at a top level.

You need to add your navigation link block of code inside navigation view closure, like mentioned below:
struct ParentView: View {
   var body: some View {
       NavigationView {
           List {
              Section {
                   ForEach(0...5, id: \.self) { i in
                       NavigationLink {
                           ChildView()
                       } label: {
                           Text("Tap here")
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }       
   }
}

Here is why,
A navigation link (NavigationLink) is a view specifically designed to work within the context of a navigation hierarchy managed by a NavigationView. It relies on the NavigationView to provide the necessary infrastructure for navigation, including the navigation bar, animations, and the overall navigation flow.
On iOS 15 or older it would use NavigationView and on iOS 16 or newer it would use NavigationStack.
Hope it helps!

The app is already providing a NavigationStack at the top level.

Have you tried my proposed solution above? Did it work? Read the paragraph below 'Here is why', it might help you understand the need to declare a navigation view.
Please share complete code, if it is still not working.

NavigationView is deprecated in favour of navigation stack…

Thanks for notifying me! On iOS 15 or older, it would use NavigationView and on iOS 16 or newer, it would use NavigationStack. I have added this statement in my answer also.

Thanks but as I’ve said, I’ve already got the top level of the app wrapped with a navigation stack so don’t think this is the issue.

My sample code works fine for me. Can you share the complete code so I can assist you further?
